# I can't figure out this circuit. How do I obtain the three currents?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I can't figure out why i2 is 0. I tried applying KVL on the mesh with the voltage source but I didn't get anywhere (perhaps I applied it incorrectly? i don't know if the current travelling through that mesh is i2 or not). I also don't know how to obtain i1 and i0 once I obtain i2. (i'm guessing the voltage is the same on the 2 and 5 resistors? but i could be wrong). A little help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Current has to go in a loop.  There is no loop for i2.

Comment: Look at the 24V source. All of the current leaving the top must go into the 10 ohm resistor. The same amount of current must come back into the bottom, so all of the resistor's current goes back to the source. None of that current can go into I2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for helping me figure it out! \$i_2\$ has to be 0 because it has no loop to go through.

So I solved the left hand side and right hand side separately and I got these results:

\$V_{\Delta} = \dfrac{10}{10 + 2} \times 24 = 20 V\$ (voltage divider)

So the current source is \$0.8 \times V_{\Delta} = 16 A\$

Then I used a current divider to get \$i_1\$ and \$i_0\$.

\$i_1 = \dfrac{5}{20 + 5} \times ( -16 ) = -3.2 A\$

\$i_0 = \dfrac{20}{20 + 5} \times ( -16 ) = -12.8 A\$

I think this is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I1 and I0 would still be exactly the same currents if the wire joining the left hand part of the circuit to the right hand part of the circuit were removed. With no wire there can be no current.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem left hand side and right hand side seperatly but keep in mind that Vdelta is the same for both side.